# Selenium not recognizing span element within a div, thinks it's text?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, text, element

I'm trying to grab the text from a span that's inside a div. The div is currently selected, so it has "curr" within its class.

The DOM:

```
<a id="ctl00_oAjaxContentPlaceHolder_LinkButtonAlerts" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$oAjaxContentPlaceHolder$LinkButtonAlerts','')">  
  <div id="ctl00_oAjaxContentPlaceHolder_divAlertAlertsHolder" class="profile-menu-alerts curr" title="Activities &amp; Alerts"> 
    <span>Activities &amp; Alerts</span>  
  </div>  
</a>
```

This XPath should find the span (it works when I use the Find tool in DevTools), but it fails to find the element

```
//div[contains(@class,'curr')]/span
```

If I remove the /span from the xpath, it finds the div just fine. And the strange part is that if I grab the text of that div with

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'curr')]")).Text;
```

it returns `"<span>Activities &amp; Alerts</span>"`. Why is this span element being incorrectly recognized as Text?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this on my solution using the below and had no issues.

var test = Driver.FindElement_byXPath("//div[contains(@class,'curr')]/span").Text;

html - added another option:

```
            <a id="ctl00_oAjaxContentPlaceHolder_LinkButtonAlerts" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$oAjaxContentPlaceHolder$LinkButtonAlerts','')">  
              <div id="ctl00_oAjaxContentPlaceHolder_divAlertAlertsHolder" class="profile-menu-alerts" title="Activities &amp; Alerts"> 
                <span>Test 1</span>  
              </div>  
            </a>
            <a id="ctl00_oAjaxContentPlaceHolder_LinkButtonAlerts" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$oAjaxContentPlaceHolder$LinkButtonAlerts','')">  
              <div id="ctl00_oAjaxContentPlaceHolder_divAlertAlertsHolder" class="profile-menu-alerts curr" title="Activities &amp; Alerts"> 
                <span>Activities &amp; Alerts</span>  
              </div>  
            </a>
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. Only one div will ever have the 'curr' class; it will be whichever button the user has last clicked, and it is highlighted. I'm trying to grab whichever div is the highlighted one, not a specific div that can be identified by the id. Regardless, the real problem I'm having is that //div[contains(@class,'curr')] finds the div element correctly, but //div[contains(@class,'curr')]/span and //div[contains(@class,'curr')]//span both fail to find the span.

Comment: Thanks for the additional context. I updated my answer but it is really the same xpath. Since we do not have a url to see the full markup pre-click, it makes it tougher. If you debug it going slower, does it work? I am wondering if you need a wait for everything to update.